# History table tree

Tags: database, database-design

I have represented a tree in a relational table. Each nodes are records that could change values, I can insert,delete or group some nodes too.

Which is the best approach to make an history table of all this changes?

Is a database design pattern avaible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't really seem like a design pattern as more a DB design.

Important question: 
1. How secure do you need this historical record? Is it safe to store in the DB itself or are you concerned that the DB might be compromised and you need an unmolestable record?

Assuming you can store this data in the db, then there isn't much to design

1. Create a trigger on whatever meta-table your DB uses to record new tables and have IT create a new trigger on the table just created. This way, it's maintenance free.
2. Gather the following information in a flat table: `who`, `what`, `when`

When you create your historical table make sure you create triggers preventing updates to any record or any deletes. The record should be `append only!`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answer.
About your security question,I haven't any restriction so I can store historical data in the DB.

Assuming that Historical data can be modeled in Relational Database,  in several techniques such as separated tables for history records and  transaction logs, I have found :

- **Row-based Auditing** - This technique creates a separated table for each
  relational table to maintain historical data. The auditing table contains every column of the operational table times; start time and end time to maintain the lifespan of
  the data. Two additional attributes; operation type and username.
- **Column-Based Auditing** - The column-based auditing solves the redundancy of
  the row-based auditing. Data in historical column of auditing table are stored only the changed value except the primary key, such as ID, which is used to reference its operational table.
- **Log-Table Auditing** - Log tables have been used for transaction management in the relational database for a long time. Due to the nature of transaction that needs to know
  operation, data, and time of execution, log tables can be utilized for the auditing purpose too.

For my problem I am guessing that the Row-based Auditing  may be a good approach because there is the possibility to track the the operation too and if I add some attribute like root - leave I can store the structure of the tree.

Do you have suggestion, from design Db point of view, or some tutorial or article in order to start the implementation ?

Thank you.